# Keep drop down list open after item is selected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have an aspx page that has two checkbox lists contained in HTML dropdown list.

one is written in HTML and show \ hides columsn in a datatable based on what is and what is not checked.

The other is a drop down with an asp.net checkbox list control so that I can easily pass values back to a database based on selected options without having to look in the `Request.Form("...")`.

An issue I am looking to resolve is how do i keep the drop downs open after a checkbox item has been clicked. The same behavior occurs in both lists \ drop downs so would hope it could be a single solution for both.

my code to build up the one list is like so

```
<div class="row" style="float: right; padding-right: 15px">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="button-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span><span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ColSelectorPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then the list is build and passed back to the place holder here

```
Dim html As New StringBuilder()

For value As Integer = 0 To dictofClassAndCol.Count
    If (value = dictofClassAndCol.Count) Then
       Exit For
    End If
    Dim item = dictofClassAndCol.ElementAt(value)
    Dim key As String = item.Key
    Dim val As String = item.Value
    Dim line = String.Format("<li style='padding-left: 10px'><label class='small' tabindex='-1'><input type='checkbox' checked='true' value='{0}'/>{1}</label></li>", key.Replace(" ", ""), val)
    html.AppendLine(line)

Next

Return html
```

The other is build like so

```
<div class="btn-group" style="padding-top: 5px">
     <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Report Status <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding-left: 10px">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="statusSelectorPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="statuscblist" runat="server">

            </asp:CheckBoxList>
     </ul>

</div>
```

Then the items are build up like this

```
If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
            For Each item In _dictOfStatus
                Dim status As New ListItem
                status.Value = item.Value
                status.Text = item.Key
                status.Selected = True
                statuscblist.Items.Add(status)
            Next
        End If
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found my answer

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#statusSelctor .dropdown-menu").on({
    "click": function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

});

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#columns .dropdown-menu").on({
    "click": function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

});
```